# Check if one (or more) value in a list contain in JSON in redshift

Tags: sql, json, database, search, amazon-redshift

I have a column in redshift that contains a JSON.
I want to create a query that checks if one value in a list exists in the JSON, and then returns the path of the value.

For example I habe those list and JSON:

```
possible_values = ["html","php","python"]
json = {"encoding":"ASCI","web":{"code_language":"php"}}
```

So I'm expected for this result:

```
TRUE, path: "web\code_language"
```

Does it possible?

Comment: There's no native way to do that in Redshift.  You'd have to write a Recursive CTE to decompose the entire json object in to its components, element by element, and check if any of them match your search array.  It's do-able, but not pretty.  So much so that I'd suggest this is much better done outside of Redshift, or that you should be decomposing the json object into structured tables when you ingest the data.  If it ***must*** be done in redshift, please could you define what is and is not possible in the json object (the schema) and what to return if there are multiple matches.

Comment: Or, write a user defined function in python / plpythonu.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html